# Angular and JS Filter upon non-standard checkboxes behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, filter

I would like create filters upon table data.

Filter should be generic (one to many filters group) and is mixed with search field. I have data, basic logic and search working, but can not find the right way to construct function which will return filtered records. All the filters have `ALL` as option, it's checked during `onLoad`, but rest checkboxes remains unchecked (customer specification), when you check one of the filter option the `ALL` is unchecked.

HTML and JS code:

```js
$scope.checkedAll = [true, true];
 
  $scope.data.items = [
  {name: "Provider", value: 'provider_id', content: [
   {name: 'Azure VM', value: 'azure_vm', selected: false},
   {name: 'CloudForms', value: 'cloudforms', selected: false}
   // more providers of them...
  ]},
  {name: "State", value: 'state_id', content: [
   {name: 'Terminated', value: 'terminated', selected: false},
   {name: 'On', value: 'on', selected: false},
   {name: 'Off', value: 'off', selected: false}
   //more states
  ]}
  //more filters []
 ];

  $scope.data.list = [
  {provider_id: "provider1", display_name: "name1", state_id: "on"},
  {provider_id: "provider2", display_name: "name2", state_id: "on"},
  {provider_id: "provider2", display_name: "name3", state_id: "off"},
  {provider_id: "provider2", display_name: "name4", state_id: "terminated"}
  //much more records
  ];

 $scope.optionClickedAll = function(index) {
  var checked = $scope.checkedAll[index];
  if (!checked) {
   return;
  }
  
  angular.forEach($scope.data.items[index].content, function (element) {
   element.selected = !checked;
  });
 }
 
 $scope.optionClicked = function(index, element) {
  var checked = element.selected;
  
  if (checked) {
   $scope.checkedAll[index] = false;
  }
  
 }
 
 $scope.filterSelected = function(list) {

  var result = [];
  
/*  var filterIds = [];
  var itemIds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.items.length; ++i) {
   var item = $scope.data.items[i];
   for (var j = 0; j < item.content.length; ++j) {
    var value = item.content[j];
    if ($scope.checkedAll[i] || value.selected) {
     if (filterIds.indexOf(item.value) == -1) filterIds.push(item.value);
     if (itemIds.indexOf(value.value) == -1) itemIds.push(value.value);
    }
   }
  }
*/

  for (var k = 0; k < list.length; ++k) {
   // ...
  return result;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 ">
<div class="filters">
    <div class="search-box">
        <label class="filter-label">FILTERS</label>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchInstances">
            <label class="">${Search}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data.items">
        <label>{{item.name|uppercase}}</label>
        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="optionClickedAll($index)" ng-model="checkedAll[$index]" id="{{item.value}}">
            <label for="{{item.value}}">All</label>
            <div ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
                <div ng-repeat="element in item.content">
                    <input class="filled-in filter-all" type="checkbox" ng-click="optionClicked(parentIndex, element)" ng-model="element.selected" id="{{element.value}}">
                    <label for="{{element.value}}">{{element.name}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 ">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Provider</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in filterSelected(data.list) | filter:searchInstances">
                <td>{{item.provider_id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.state_id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.display_namy}}</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

It's possible to change structure of `$scope.data.items`. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports custom filter which is probably what you want. Take a look at the AngularJS documentation [Creating custom filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). You will also find an example there.

Comment: I forget to mention that I can not use the custom filters, because this code is running on ServiceNow platform and Angular has some limitations here.